# Spring boot with spring data neo4j, database access path

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

in spring boot application with spring data neo4j
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-neo4j-data-rest/
I do not understand in which db is it access? I am running neo4j server with default db, I created nodes, but app did not find any data.
How I can change the path?

Comment: by default it's going to access db with name [graph]
however you can specify any name in your application.proproperties file & Spring  will create db with that name as well,
Also, you can't run neo4j Browser & spring boot application at same time.
It'll thrown exception.

Comment: for better anwser , provide me with code responsible